# What package is meant to replace thinkfinger in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, fingerprint-reader

My laptop has a fingerprint reader that until 11.10 I used via thinkfinger.  That package is no longer in the repositories, but I assume there’s a different package meant to support fingerprint readers in thinkfinger’s place.  What is the recommended fingerprint reader package?  Should I just find thinkfinger on my own and use that instead?

Here’s my reader’s lsusb output:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 SGS Thomson Microelectronics Fingerprint Reader
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the same fingerprint reader as me. My Googling turned up this: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fingerprint-gui It works flawlessly for me.

Comment: sadly it appears that there’s no fingerprint reader support in the repositories, but i installed fingerprint-gui from a ppa for 12.04 and it works great!